# Capitalization of descriptive words referring to a proper noun

Tags: capitalization

Which of the following is the correct choice for capitalizing (or not capitalizing) "bay mouth", and why?

1. Mission Bay is a popular tourist location, with small waves near the bay mouth.
2. Mission Bay is a popular tourist location, with small waves near the Bay mouth.

My intuition is that the first sentence is correct and that "bay mouth" should not be capitalized.
Could someone help explain how to make the proper choice here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the first sentence, Bay is part of a proper name (Mission Bay) and therefore capitalized. In the second sentence, bay is the word for a geographic feature (a bay) and therefore not capitalized.